# Value Calculation ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to calculate the total amount by multiplying the UnitAmount and the Qty user has entered.
Then I need to pass that total amount to the Total amount label field. So far this is my code,

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
       Unit Amount
      <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Unit_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Unit_Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      Requesting Qty
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        Total Amount
          <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I also got the jquery for this, but I think I'm doing it the wrong way.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Qty').on('change', function (evt) {
            var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
            var rate = Number($row.find('.Unit_Amount').text());
            var qty = Number($(this).val());
            var total = rate * qty;
            $row.find('.Total').text(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can you help me to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a unique class name to three of the items.

Like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control totalLabel" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control qtyPrice" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Unit_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control unitAmount" } })
```

And in your script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Qty').on('change', function () {
        var qtyamount = $('.qtyPrice').val();
        var unitamount = $('.unitAmount').val();
        var total = qtyamount*unitamount;

        $(".totalLabel").text(total);
    });
});
```

I think this should work.

**EDIT**

Working example : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4gyp9hq/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have tried this. Your code seems to be working, but when I applied to mine nothings shows up. can you recheck this and let me know where I'm doing it wrong.?    ** ` <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Total Amount
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                           <label id="totalLabel" class="form-control totalLabel"></label>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`**

Comment: @smcdevelpments Try this: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.form-control qtyPrice').on('change', function () {
        var qtyamount = $('.form-control qtyPrice').val();
        var unitamount = $('.form-control qtyPrice').val();
        var total = qtyamount*unitamount;

        $(".form-control qtyPrice").text(total);
    });
});`

Comment: Nope :( . Tried this also. I have a doubt that for the output label Im using like this.  will it this would be a problem ?? `<label id="totalLabel" class="form-control totalLabel"></label>`

Comment: If you assigned an id to it you should put a '#' insted of '. '

Comment: I have tried that also,. But not showing the total value

Comment: @smcdevelpments https://jsfiddle.net/j4gyp9hq/1/ here is the working example. You can fix your problems by looking at this.